# Сообщение об успешной отправки формы

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

В приложении реализованном на asp.net mvc5 есть форма для заполнения, по нажатию на submit происходит проверка на обязательные поля (на клиентской части) и если все хорошо выполняется отправка. Необходимо что бы если проверки прошли и все хорошо, на экране появлялось сообщение что форма отправлена. Как можно подобное сделать???

Проверка вот такая :

```
function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["1"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert('Необходимо заполнить поле 1');
            return false;
        }
        var y = document.forms["myForm"]["2"].value;
        if (y == null || y == "") {
            alert('Необходимо заполнить поле 2');
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: При чем тут тег java?

Comment: Полезный вопрос и полезный ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у тебя на сервере метод отрабатывающий HTTPPOST формы, там делаешь return RedirectToAction("Имя action с сообщением что всё хорошо")